# When doing a strcmp in php from mysql it returns -6

Tags: php, mysql, strcmp

I am having a similiar issue where when I pull a value back from mysql it always returns   a -6 when I compare it to a filename. It only happens when I pull the information from mysql

```
path rp_suzrl250.jpg strFile rp_suzrl250.jpg  
strcmp value -6 



path 2009_Evo.jpg strFile 2009_Evo.jpg  
strcmp value -6  

path DSCF6495.JPG strFile DSCF6495.JPG  
strcmp value -6
    $strFile = $dbrow[bikepicture]; 
    if($dh = opendir($file)){
        while(($path = readdir($dh)) !== false){
            $path = (string)$path;
            $strFile = (string)$strFile;
            echo "filename:  " . $path . "  " . strcmp($path, $strFile) . "<br>";
            if ($path ===  $strFile){
                echo $path . " got here " . "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
    if (strtoupper($path) === strtoupper($strFile)){  }
```

Casting to a string fails and going to upper fails.  It returns a -6.

Comment: Are both strings (according to strlen()) same sized? Maybe there are some non-printable characters anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

My "answer" consists of questions only, but they will likely lead you to a solution.

Is your $strFile a string? What do you get with var_dump($strFile)?
I'd assume, that your code snippet goes inside a loop of this kind:

```
$results = $cnn->query($query);
while ($dbrow = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ...
}
```

If that is correct, you should use $strFile = $dbrow['bikepicture'], because otherwise bikepicture is interpreted as a constant. Don't you get warnings/errors, by the way?